# How to deploy my React project on Vercel?

Tags: reactjs, vercel

I am gonna deploy my project on Vercel.
But I couldn't do it because the error message prevented me.
The message was like below.

Error: The file "/vercel/path0/dist/routes-manifest.json" couldn't be found. This is often caused by a misconfiguration in your project.

So I had googling so that I set some configurations.
But still, I couldn't deploy it.
How can I deploy it?